# Automatic import refactoring when moving Typescript files in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Suppose we have an import `./file` and we move it to `./container/file`.  This breaks all the typescript imports for file.  Anyone know of a plugin for VSCode that will automatically refactor the modules importing `file`?

Comment: The latest version of vscode does this automatically. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_update-import-paths-when-a-file-is-moved-or-renamed) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_move-to-new-file-refactoring)

Comment: Coo!  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the [extension move-import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.move-imports) would work for you

> Automatically move/rename imports when you rename/move your project files
>
> - Support multiple file extensions (although actual module renaming is only available in js, jsx, ts, tsx files)

It seems buggy though, according to the comments.

The extension [Move TS - Move TypeScript files and update relative imports](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts) seems more reliable.

> Moves TypeScript files and folders containing TypeScript and updates their relative import paths.

Note: on VSCode, the official issue for this feature is [Microsoft/TypeScript issue 6487](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6487).
It is supposed to be implemented in [TypeScript release v2.9.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v2.9.1).
See "[Rename file and move declaration to new file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#rename-move-file)".